# Scanning a web page and find some specific texts and their attributes

Tags: parsing

I am looking for an Open Source software tool to read and save specific texts and their attributes from a web page (I have knowledge of programming language like C, Java, Groovy etc.)

**What I like to do:**
Everyday, I receive an email from my real estate agent with a link of a web page where all the houses for sale are listed with their features and attributes. I would like to automate to read and save the 'key' features and their respective data value in a file (.csv).

e.g. (as seen in the image below), I would like to read 'Apx Sqft:' and its value 500-599 and save in a .csv file.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0EBzV.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have created a real estate website scraper with Ruby on Rails.  Try it out to see if it meets your need (it is open source)

https://github.com/RealEstateWebTools/property_web_scraper